# How can I load an AngularJs app only after API response?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I have an Angular application. I need it to load ONLY after a succesful call to an API which returning data is needed for said app.

Is there a way to achieve this within Angular itself?

Ideally it should look something like this:

```
userData.fetch('/data').then(
  function(res){ 
    // Succesful call
    Application.loads();
  },
  function(res){
    // API is not responding. Don't load application
  }
);
```

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, you could always use `ng cloak`. if you are worrying about data handle in controller then you could always resolve the promise to see if you fetch data from service or rest.

Comment: What should happen if the API call fails? Don't load the application is somewhat vague. I mean the application has to load to make the above call. When it fails how will the user know it's failed?

Comment: Use `ui-router` to define your states, and load the data needed before the state is loaded. You should have a look at `resolve`. It will load the data, when loaded init the state and the controller. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki